# How to create a button on the Entry Edit page?

Tags: channel-entries, channel-entries-api, api

Basically, what i'm attempting to do is create a [button] right next to the entry save/submit button that will grab the current entries entry_id and pass it to a page we control.

I'm staring at the channel_entry api, but that's not really what i need at the moment. https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/development/api/api_channel_entries.html  am i looking at the wrong api?

Google search for "add button to entry edit page in expression engine" doesn't really give me any valuable results either.

Anyone know where i should start? or what files i should make changes to?

Comment: Is this something that you want sent *everytime* an entry is saved, but only when an entry is saved? If so, you should probably be looking at writing an EE extension.

Comment: No, the idea is that once the url contains entry_id, I want a button to show up next to the submit button, so that i can pass the entry_id to a popup page that I will build out some stuff into. I just need a clean way to pass that entry_id without too much brain use on the users end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no API for adding anything other than fieldtypes or tabs to the entry screen. I'd suggest one of two options:

1. Build a [fieldtype](https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/development/fieldtypes.html) which displays your button and adds the javascript you need, then place a field which uses this fieldtype as the last field on the screen.
2. Build an [accessory](https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/development/accessories.html) which simply injects some javascript into the edit entry screen in order to add your button and behaviours under the appropriate circumstances.